# How to put Play! controllers in an arbitrary sub-package

Tags: java, model-view-controller, view, controller, playframework

I'm using the Play Framework for a web app in Java.

I'd like to put an Account controller in an "account" subpackage, for example:

```
|- controllers
   |- account
      |- Account.java
```

While my views are organized like:

```
|- views
   |- Account
      |- index.html
```

The Account.java file contains:

```
package controllers.account;

import play.mvc.Controller;

public class Account extends Controller {

    public static void index() {
        render();
    }

}
```

I'd like to have the following behavior:

when a request is made to `http://localhost/account/{action}`, it's redirected to the `Account.java` controller that shows the view in the `Account` folder.

Any tips?

Comment: How to configure routes with these subpackages ? I tried like :-              GET     /                controllers.Account.Application.index       but its not working were account is my subpackage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried putting your views in a structure that matches your controller structure?

```
|- views
   |- account
      |- Account
         |- index.html
```

Beside that, you can always pass in the view name to the render() call:

```
render("Account/index.html");
```

I personally would always stick to the built-in structure that is supplied with play. Otherwise you could easily end up in refactoring hell, when you rearrange your controller structure somewhere down the road...

Answer (score 7):

If you do create a package structure, note that there's a few new syntaxes that are non-obvious:

**Reverse lookup of controller**

Put the package name between 'controllers' and 'routes':

```
controllers.account.routes.Account.index
```

E.g. in a view

```
<a href="@controllers.account.routes.Account.index" class="btn">Exit</a
```

**View references in controller**

Package name follows 'views.html':

```
return ok(views.html.account.index.render());
```

Comment: How to configure routes with these subpackages ? I tried like :-              GET     /                controllers.Account.Application.index       but its not working were account is my subpackage.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reference a controller located in a sub package from a view 
and use some structure like this

```
  |- com
    |- company
      |- system
        |- controllers
          |- MyController
  |- views
    |- index.html
```

and a route configured in conf/routes as

```
GET        /api/hello com.company.system.controllers.MyController.hello
```

one can use following to create a link to the method hello from the view

```
<a href="@com.company.system.controllers.routes.MyController.hello">Hello!</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the route on conf/routes. Something like:
*       /account/${action}  account.Account.${action}