# play 2.3 Subproject routing "not a member" Error

Tags: playframework-2.3

I'm having trouble routing my subproject, but I think I followed all the steps to include my subproject

```
|- mainProject
 |- app
 |- conf
 |- modules
  |- subProject
   |- app
    |- assets
    |- controllers
     |- subProject
      |- Application.scala
      |- Assets.scala
      |- MyCode.java
    |- models
     |- subProject
      |- MyModel.java
    |- views
     |- subProject
      |- myView.scala.html
    |- conf
     |- subProject.routes
```

subProject.routes

```
GET     /                           subProject.app.controllers.subProject.MyCode.index()
POST    /add                        subProject.app.controllers.subProject.MyCode.add
POST    /edit/:id                   subProject.app.controllers.subProject.MyCode.edit(id: Long)
GET     /load/:id                   subProject.app.controllers.subProject.MyCode.load(id: Long)
GET     /list                       subProject.app.controllers.subProject.MyCode.list()

# Map static resources from the /public folder to the /assets URL path
GET     /assets/*file               subProject.app.controllers.subProject.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
GET     /webjars/*file              controllers.WebJarAssets.at(file)
GET     /javascriptRoutes           subProject.app.controllers.subProject.Application.javascriptRoutes()
```

myview contains this line:

```
<script src="@controllers.subProject.routes.Assets.at("javascripts/myJavascript.js")"></script>
```

And I still get the error

```
[error] /path/git/mainProject/module/subProject/app/views/subProject/myview.scala.html:8: object subProject is not a member of package controllers
[error]     <script src="@controllers.subProject.routes.Assets.at("javascripts/myJavascript.js")"></script>
[error]                               ^
[error] one error found
[error] (subProject/compile:compile) Compilation failed
[error] Total time: 1 s, completed 07-Apr-2015 17:21:56
```

I think my routes file is wrong, but if I do it like in the doc

```
GET     /                           controllers.subProject.myCode.index()
```

I get

```
[error] /path/git/mainProject/modules/subProject/conf/subProject.routes:6: object MyCode is not a member of package controllers.subProject
[error] GET     /                           controllers.subProject.MyCode.index()
```

searching for [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6499078/how-to-put-play-controllers-in-an-arbitrary-sub-package/29496159) problems didn't help

what am I doing wrong?

*edit:* I just found this problem is masking another problem with the reversed routes

```
[error] /path/git/mainProject/modules/subProject/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/controllers/subProject/routes.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
[error] public static final controllers.subProject.ReverseMyCode MyCode = new controllers.subProject.ReverseMyCode();
[error]                                        ^
[error]   symbol:   class ReverseMyCode
[error]   location: package controllers.subProject
[error] /path/git/mainProject/modules/subProjecy/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/controllers/subProject/routes.java:11: error: package controllers.subProject.javascript does not exist
[error] public static final controllers.subProject.javascript.ReverseMyCode MyCode = new controllers.subProject.javascript.ReverseMyCode();
[error]                                                   ^
[error] /path/git/mainProject/modules/subProject/target/scala-2.10/src_managed/main/controllers/subProject/routes.java:16: error: package controllers.subProject.ref does not exist
[error] public static final controllers.subProject.ref.ReverseMyCode MyCode = new controllers.subProject.ref.ReverseMyCode();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the same problem. I suppose the package of `MyCode.java` is `modules.subProject.app.controllers.subProject.MyCode` ?

That's because of your IDE that creates your classes in packages.
The package of the files of your subproject must start with `controllers.subProject.`

And your `subProject.routes` file must be

```
GET     /                           controllers.subProject.MyCode.index()
POST    /add                        controllers.subProject.MyCode.add
POST    /edit/:id                   controllers.subProject.MyCode.edit(id: Long)
GET     /load/:id                   controllers.subProject.MyCode.load(id: Long)
GET     /list                       controllers.subProject.MyCode.list()
```

For the reversed routes error, just clean your project `activator clean compile`

Comment: Thank you, works like a charm.I really need to stop trying to satisfy eclipse